# Is $(\sum_{n\geq 0}|P_n(z)|^2)^{1/2}$ entire?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $(P_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a sequence of real polynomials with $\deg P_n=n$ such that $\sum_{n\geq 0}|P_n(z)|^2$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. We have by Cauchy's Criterion, Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and Morera's theorem that $\sum_{n\geq 0}(P_n(z))^2$ defines an entire function. The question is,

> Is $(\sum_{n\geq 0}|P_n(z)|^2)^{1/2}$ entire?

What I am unsure about is that $\sum_{n\geq 0}|P_n(z)|^2$ can not be entire, because for instance at some terms in this series, we have $\overline{z}$ or even $|z|$, which are not holomorphic (take, for example $g(z):=az+b$ which is holomorphic, while $|g|$ is not holomorphic). I do not know how to figure out whether or not it is holomorphic after squaring it.

Comment: An entire function by open mapping theorem cannot take only real values unless it is constant

Comment: @CalvinKhor I do not understand it. Could you please elaborate? In the Open Mapping Theorem, it says "Let $f$ be a non-constant **holomorphic** funition in a domain $G\subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Then $f(G)$ is a domain in $\mathbb{C}$."

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by entire function, if not holomorphic in $\mathbb C$? Such functions of course restrict to holomorphic functions in every domain $G$? And are you aware what a domain is? Can you see that the range of e.g. $\sqrt{1+|z|^2}$ is not a domain in $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor By entire, I mean it is holomorphic on whole $\mathbb{C}$. What I am confused is, how you used Open Mapping Theorem to conclude that it is entire ... is it by the contrapositive argument, or how?

Comment: I am not concluding anywhere it is entire. My comment starts by **assuming** it is entire, and deriving a contradiction via open mapping theorem. Thus no such function is entire. (a minor point, I do not understand why you chose to emphasize **holomorphic**; it seems we are on the same page for the definition of entire)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Okay, so you start assuming, on the contrary, that $h(z):=(\sum_{n\geq 0}|P_n(z)|^2)^{1/2}$ is entire. Then, we would get that $h(\mathbb{C})$ is a domain in $\mathbb{C}$, by the Open Mapping Theorem. Then, how do you see that $h(\mathbb{C})$ actually is not a domain?

Comment: Can you see that the range of e.g. $\sqrt{1+|z|^2}$ is not a domain? If no, please give the defintion of a domain

Comment: @CalvinKhor Uhm, your expression is same as $\sqrt{1+a^2 + b^2}$, where $z=a+ib$, not sure what to do from there. The definition is: "An open set $G\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is called a domain, if any two points $P$ and $Q$ in $G$ can be connected by a staircase line in $G$."

Comment: You surely must know what $\{ \sqrt{1+a^2+b^2} : a\in\mathbb R, b\in \mathbb R\}$ is! Further hint - a domain is an **open** set

Comment: @CalvinKhor Okay, that set represents all points on the the "curve" (resembles $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ on $[1,\infty)$). Since we can not choose two points on that "curve" to be connected by a staircase, because this staircase is outside your set, so it can not be a domain. Sounds good, no?

Comment: No, your argument is faulty because you are relying on odd english like "staircases". Your proof equally says that you cannot connect 0 to 1 by a straight line in any domain, because you need a "staircase". What the english is hiding is that you can also use "staircases without steps up". So a suggestion, don't argue by using "staircases"

Comment: Secondly, I am not asking for a parameterisation of the set $\{ \sqrt{1+a^2+b^2} : a\in\mathbb R, b\in \mathbb R\}$, I was asking for a much simpler purely set theoretic description...

Comment: Apologies, what if "staircase line" is understood as "to draw a curve from $P$ and $Q$ inside $G$ and consisting of horizontal and vertical line segments"? To your last comment, your set is closed in set-theoretic sense, I did not think of that way till now. Sorry, I got it now. Thanks a lot for your patience

Comment: No, not enough, because its not precise (at least not precise enough to you, because you don't understand). Somehow I feel like I'm not getting through. You do not need at least one vertical line segment. And I did not ask for the set's properties, I want you to identify the set, was that not clear?

Comment: Oh, I think i see what you mean by pointing out that its closed. The fact that its closed is correct but does not imply its not open

Comment: You don't need Open Mapping Theorem. Cauchy Riemann equations show that only real valued holomorphic functions on any open connected set are constants.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes, that is what I should have said, thanks